# Creating new pyspark columns dynamically when the output of a udf is a dictionary

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Context: Let's say we have a PySpark DataFrame and we'd like to add new columns to this dataframe dynamically.

```
#import packages 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

#create spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('example').getOrCreate()

#create dataframe
data = [('John',25),('Smith',30),('Adam',58),('Henry',45)]

#create dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema = ['Name', 'Age'])
```

We may have a UDF function that outputs a dictionary as such:

```
def custom_udf(row,param1,param2):

  # function steps using param1 and param2
  ...
  return {
        "col1":0,
        "col2":1
    }
```

We can then register our UDF a such:

```
udf_output= udf(lambda row: custom_udf(row, param1=amodel, param2=vectorizer), MapType(StringType(), IntegerType()))
```

How can we then use this udf_output to create new pyspark columns where each column is the `key` of the udf_output and the value of the new row is the `value` pair for that same column?

I was trying something like this:

```
df_output = df.withColumn("new_columns", udf_output(F.struct([df[x] for x in df.columns])))
for key, value in df_output.select("new_columns").collect().items(): 
       df_output = df_output.withColumn(key, F.lit(value))
```

But I keep getting errors such as `An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'TypeError: sequence item 5: expected str instance, int found'`

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe this will be useful: https://mungingdata.com/pyspark/dict-map-to-multiple-columns/

Answer (score 1):

Okay finally managed to solve it however if anyone has a method without using collect (quite slow) feel free to share it :

```
def python_func(row, model):
    ...

    return dict
       
udf_expand_columns = udf(lambda row: python_func(row, model=model), MapType(StringType(), StringType()))

# Create a column of type MapType given the UDF that was registered
df = df.withColumn("dict_map", udf_expand_columns(
    f"{model_name}_text"))

# Select the keys of the dict_map dictionary (dict_map is a column seen as a dictionary)
keys_df = df.select(
    F.explode(F.map_keys(F.col("dict_map")))).distinct()

# Collect the keys
keys = list(map(lambda row: row[0], keys_df.collect()))
# Get the keys and the respective values
key_cols = list(
    map(lambda f: F.col("dict_map").getItem(f).alias(str(f)), keys))
# Get the final columns from the dict_map + all the columns from the original dataframe
final_cols = [c for c in df.columns] + key_cols
# Select everything
df = df.select(final_cols)
df = df.drop("dict_map")
```